# Is there a shortcut to calculate eigendecomposition of a singular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that at least one of the eigenvalues are zero, but is there any other way to ease the eigendecomposition?

Comment: @Gae.S. Frankly, I didn't understand :) $A-\lambda I$ is always singular, so why would it depend on $A$?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful trick for singular matrices which works particularly well if $A$ has "very low" rank. If $A$ is of size $n$ and rank $r<n$, then we can compute a [rank-factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization) $A = CF$ where $C,F$ are of full rank with sizes $n \times r, r \times n$ respectively. Note that such a factorization can be computed using only row-reduction.

We find that the non-zero eigenvalues of $A$ are precisely equal to the eigenvalues of the $r \times r$ matrix $FC$. Moreover, if $x$ is an eigenvector of $FC$ with $FC = \lambda x$, then $Cx$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with
$$
A(Cx) = C(FC)x = C (\lambda x) = \lambda Cx.
$$
If $A$ is diagonalizable, then it can be diagonalized as follows: let $P$ be any matrix such that $[C \ \ P]$ is invertible. Taking $S = [C \ \ P]$, we find that $S^{-1}AS$ is diagonal.